# Использование Compass для удаленных папок по FTP

Tags: вёрстка, sass, compass

Использую Compass на локалке для SASS.  Как установить и пользоваться Compass для удаленных папок по FTP.

Comment: можно и без compass сохранять файлы, используя SFTP. или я не так понял вопрос?

Comment: Разрабатываете под какой ОС?

Comment: Работаю под Win10. Интересно есть ли возможность установить Compass на удаленном сервере, или как то при сохранении файла sass на локалке производилась автоматическая компиляция и сохранение на удаленном сервере.